# Three finger drag not working on trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, ui, gesture

I just got the new macbook and the three finger drag does not work in a limited area of the trackpad (between center and top left). I've got a new one and it has the same problem.

Did anyone find the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

yes same here. I had a senior adviser on the phone and apparently they are aware of it, and working to resolve the issue. Should be fixed in the next update.